# Change slide background using CSS with Quarto/reveal.js

Tags: r, reveal.js, quarto

I am writing a `.scss` file to theme a reveal.js slide deck using quarto, and can't figure out how to set the background for a class of slides.

I would like to create a slide class with (say) a red background that I can apply with (eg) `## Slide title {.redslide}`

At the moment my .scss file includes:

```
.redslide {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Which changes background for the div that has the slide contents to red, but not the whole background.

I can change the background slide-by-slide with (eg)

`## Slide title {data-background-color=red}`

which changes the background for the whole slide and also appropriately changes the text colour to white, but trying to set `data-background-color` in the css file doesn't work.

Is it possible to set the slide background using CSS, or is there a better way to achieve this using quarto/reveal.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to add `!important`, then the those two approaches deliver the same result for me.

### **.qmd**

```
title: "Title Slide"
format: 
   revealjs:
     theme: [style.scss]
---



## Slide {background-color="#447099"}


## Slide Background {.test-background}
```

**styles.scss**

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/


.test-background {
    background-color: #447099 !important;
}
```